# Protect/Unprotect chart sheets

Tags: vba, excel

So I have these simple subs to unprotect than protect stuff while my macros are running, only problem is that some of my sheets are actually charts and they don't get protected when these subs are called. How can I change my code to incorporate the Charts as well? Thanks!

```
Sub UnprotectAll()

  Dim AdminPassword As String
  AdminPassword = "password"

  ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ("Evaluate(AdminPassword)")

  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Unprotect Password:=AdminPassword
  Next sh

End Sub

Sub ProtectAll()

  Dim AdminPassword As String
  AdminPassword = "password"

  ActiveWorkbook.Protect ("Evaluate(AdminPassword)")

  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Protect Password:=AdminPassword
  Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` by `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets`

Comment: And it works! So that's the difference between using worksheets & sheets?

Comment: Yes, Sheets refers to both Chart sheets and Worksheets.